# Performance Difference between parsing an XML in c vs Using a external Library for parsing and later implementing logic?

Tags: java, python, c, xml

I am working on a personal project, which requires me to parse a HTML4/5 webpages (typically a web page parser), and to apply certain filters and logics to collect artifacts. The project does not require to parse the content, i am interested only in the HTML tags and its relation.

I have 2 workflows with me now,

1. Use an existing library, like JAVA SAX / C - libxml2 / Python- lxml with Beautiful Soup. The problem i see is, if i use a library, there will be an initial operation to parse the whole structure, (lxml has ability to provide an iterator / or SAX for that matter an event based on open / close of tag), followed by me adding logic by again iterating over every tag and collecting artifacts.
2. Write a minimal parser in C, which will parse only what i need. It will be a single iteration from start of web page to end of web page. I will keep collecting all the artifacts like parent -> child relation, siblings relation, attributes in the tag, .. etc. By the time, i reach the end node, i should be having a complete data structure which i can export it. I also have option to write other logical operations on a separate thread as i am parsing the main file.

Which one is ideal and which one will be faster.

Performance and CPU cycles is are concern here as i am planning to deploy it to AWS cloud.

I have already started working on the 2nd approach. I am like 60% done with development.

Here are some of the performance stats,

Testing Page : Yahoo Home Page (has lot of tags and reference links)

C Program  (custom parser - no external libs used) : Avg Time : 0.01576 seconds.
Python Beautiful Soup (lxml) : Avg Time : 0.003 Seconds. (Confuse how this can be faster ?)

I am really confused how this can be faster than c program ? Please let me know if my approach is correct or am i missing something here.

Comment: Probably your C code is very inefficient. There are a lot of ways to code this in C inefficiently (e.g; using `strlen` of long strings inf the end condifion of a loop, `realloc`ating bytes too often, copying data around without need etc. . Hard to tell without actually seeing the code.

Comment: Spare yourself the time and debugging efforts and just use a library (unless you really enjoy writing the parser as an exercise, then by all means, continue).

Comment: @Michael. Yes even i doubt that. Let me try to use libxml2 and get some performance results.

Comment: as [these benchmarks prove](https://github.com/miloyip/nativejson-benchmark) (read them [here](https://rawgit.com/miloyip/nativejson-benchmark/master/sample/performance_Corei7-4980HQ@2.80GHz_mac64_clang7.0.html)) there are significant differences within the same language (C) when it comes to coding and performance.

Comment: Thanks !!. I am still looking at the code. I think the issue is i am not buffering the data while reading from a file .I use fgetc() to get a char and parse it. All my logics will be performed on this char before it retrieves the next. I think i should use fread() for buffering . I am modifying the code to get the results..

Comment: there is a bunch of libraries in java to deal with the html pages, i.e. jsoup, htmlcleaner, ...

Comment: The C libraries provide buffering, so you don't need to do it yourself.